# Free SOAP libraries for objective c

Tags: objective-c, soap

Are there any open source libraries for objective C that allow you to communicate with a SOAP based web servers. Manually working with SOAP flavoured XML is far from fun!

If there are none, +1 for info any non free libraries.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only way is to generate a stub class from the WSDL description using a project like http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ and then incorporating that in your code.

I've added a project on Github which shows how to use different libraries for SOAP and REST, and also to deserialize the responses, in JSON, XML and other formats, right here: https://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient which might be helpful for you.